# What is next() doing in this Express route and why is its order in the code important?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm getting confused with `next();` I read through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390356/what-is-next-in-this-code) which essentially says it passes control to the next route. In my code below, having `next();` where it is causes me to get "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client". However, if I comment that out and then restore the `else` clause of my if statement, it functions correctly both when an incorrect empID is passed as well as when a correct one is. I'm hoping someone could explain what exactly is happening? Why does the position of the `next()` matter? It seems like it would be called either way?

I'm trying to do what is happening in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695629/what-is-the-parameter-next-used-for-in-express) which is add a value to, say `req.user`, but I haven't been able to get that to work at all so I'm trying the method I have here.

```
let checkEmp = (req, res, next) => {
    db.get("select * from Employee where id = $id", {$id: req.empID},
        (err, row) => {
            if (err || row === undefined) {
                res.status(404).send();
            // } else {
            //     next();
            }
        });
    next();
};

// get all timesheets
timesheetRouter.get("/", getParams, checkEmp, (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.empID) {
        db.all("select * from Timesheet where employee_id = $id", {$id: req.empID},
            (err, rows) => {
                if (err) {
                    next(err);
                } else {
                    return res.status(200).send({timesheets: rows});
                }
            });
    } else {
        return res.status(404).send("Nothing to see here");
    }
});
```

Comment: Which `next` are you talking about?

Comment: checkEmp is executed first - which sends response to client - followed by the main function which also sends response to client . - now if checkEmp sends the response then you cannot send a response again - as the connection to the client is closed - but your next function from checkEmp is the main function of your route tries to send the response again and fails with that error.

Comment: Looks like `db.get()` is probably asynchronous, so in the example as shown, `next()` will be called before `db.get()` finishes and it moves on to the next handler.  Then, when the `db.get()` finishes, it tries to send a response, but the response has already been sent by the anonymous function in the main handler.

Comment: @Chase the `next()` on bottom line of checkEmp.

Comment: @JimPerris so by moving the `next()` inside of `db.get()` I'm essentially waiting for it to finish before moving on?

Comment: @nathanjw  That's correct.

Comment: @JimPerris can you move your comment into an answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `db.get()` is probably asynchronous, so in the example as shown, `next()` will be called before `db.get()` finishes and it moves on to the next handler. Then, when the `db.get()` finishes, it tries to send a response, but the response has already been sent by the anonymous function in the main handler. By moving the `next()` inside of `db.get()`, you're essentially waiting for it to finish before moving on.