# Node asynchronous route code

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express

I'm using node with express 4.0. I can't find anything on the internet (including the docs) about embedding asynchronous code in a route.

With a middleware it's quite simple:

```
app.use('/something', function (req, res, next)
{
  doSomethingAsync(function(err, probablySomethingElse)
  {
    // probably some error checking
    next();
  });
});
```

The problem with routes is that there is no `next` callback, so how does express know when to move to the next job?

```
app.get('/something', function (req, res)
{
  res.render('someTemplate');
  // no next() here, but it still works
});
```

If I had to guess, I'd say that express moves to the next task right after the above function exits. But out of curiosity I've launched the following code...

```
app.get('/something', function (req, res, next)
{
  console.log(next);
});
```

...and there actually is some `next` callback passed. So what's going on here? How does it work behind the scenes? And how can I put asynchronous code there?

Comment: Could you be a little clearer, what async code do you want to put in the route, and how is that related to the `next` callback, which all routes happen to have.

Comment: When you `res.render()` something, you don't need to call `next()` (even if it is passed so that you *could* if you wanted to) because it's the **end of the chain**.

Comment: Express somehow needs to know when my callback exits so it can close the socket and drop the data associated with this request. Do I understand correctly, that if I call `res.render` it will asume that there are no async tasks scheduled and it doesn't have to wait for `next` to be called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Express will wait until you call `res.render` to close the socket. Which means that you can pass `res.render` into a callback that takes X secs to execute and everything will still work.

The `next` allows you to go to the next route that maps your value, you can find a very good explanation here: [What is the parameter "next" used for in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695629/node-js-express-next)

But under what you are asking here. The moment `render()` is called on the `res` object, then data will be sent and the socket closed.