# Nested api endpoints in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm developing a REST API using expressjs.
I've two api endpoints as below:

```
router.get('/probe/:id', function() {});
router.get('/:id', function() {});
```

Now, when I call the first endpoint, the second endpoint is also called(with id as 'probe').
How can I make sure that only the first one is called?
I've defined them in the order as shown above.

**EDIT**
I was indeed calling `next()` in one of the `else` of my conditions.
Now, I've a new bug.
When I call the endpoint `/probe/` - means there is no `id` then only the second route is called and the first route is never called. 

This the only time my code fails now. 
 What am I missing here?

Comment: What are you doing inside that first function? are you calling `res.end();` or maybe have a `next();` somewhere?

Comment: Check to see if you have `next()` in your first route, if it is in there `next()` tells express to continue with any other matching routes (which is why it will trigger two routes). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695629/what-is-the-parameter-next-used-for-in-express) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I'm calling `res.json()` which calls `res.end();`

Comment: are you using any other middleware with the webapp?

Comment: I was calling `next()` in one of my conditions which caused the said behaviour. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended that you use [router.route](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router.route) to define your routes in order to avoid duplicate route names. You'll need to refactor your code like so:

```
router.route('/:id')
  .get(function() {});

router.route('/probe/:id')
  .get(function() {});
```

It is also recommended that you serve your REST API from an `/api` endpoint.

```
app.use('/api', router);
```