# Callback from route.param query

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have the following routes in my server:

```
// Fetch the information (description and tags) of a post
router.get('/:post_id/information', function(req, res) {
  User.findById(req.params.post_id)
      .select('data.title.text tags')
      .exec(function(req, post) {

    res.json(post);
  });
});

// Fetch the media object of a post
router.get('/:post_id/media', function(req, res) {
  User.findById(req.params.post_id)
      .select('data.media')
      .exec(function(req, post) {

    res.json(post);
  });
});
```

And I was trying to create a callback trigger to the route parameter `post_id`, like so:

```
// Associated with the parameter 'post_id' - executed for every route
router.param('post_id', function(req, res, next, post_id) {
  Post.findById(post_id, function (err, post){
    if(err) { throw err; }

    // if no post is found
    if(!post) {
      return res.status(404).send({ message: { post: 'There is no such post.'} });
      // something bad happened! The requested post does not exist.
    }

    req.post = post;
    return next();
  });
});
```

But, after executing this callback trigger, I would like to continue to perform my queries (`select` methods) depending on the route.

How can I achieve this? Is this possible? At first, I was replacing `User.findById()` with `req.post`, but this does not work since `req.post` is the actual object resulting from the first query.

Answer (score 0):

To continue call another routes, you can put inside `if` condition:

```
// Associated with the parameter 'timeline_id' - executed for every route
router.param('post_id', function(req, res, next, post_id) {
  Post.findById(post_id, function (err, post){
    if (err) {
    return next(new Error("Couldn't find user: " + err));
  }

    // if no post is found
    if(!post) {
      return res.status(404).send({ message: { post: 'There is no such timeline.'} });
      // something bad happened! The requested timeline does not exist.
      next();
    }

    req.post = post;
    next();
  });
});
```

[Want see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695629/what-is-the-parameter-next-used-for-in-express)

Comment: That is what I have in my code! The problem is that, then, for my routes I get the following error `(req.post).select(...).exec is not a function`!

Comment: Actually, with select it wouldn't be a problem, I could manually get the required information into a new object. But what if I want to use `populate` after? The same error occurs: `(req.post).populate(...).exec is not a function`