# Why do we await next when using koa routers?

Tags: koa, koa-router, koa2

Why do we do this

```
router.get('/data', async (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.body = dummyjson.parse(data);
  await next();
});

router.get('/data/:x', async (ctx, next) => {
  const newData = dataRepeat.replace('%(x)', ctx.params.x);
  ctx.body = dummyjson.parse(newData);
  await next();
});
```

What is the use of `await next()`

It would work just fine without that. Similar thing was expected with koa 1. `yield next` was added at the end of the router.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695629/what-is-the-parameter-next-used-for-in-express) is for Express, not Koa but its basically the same reasoning.

Comment: You need to read on how Koa utilized Generators and Iterators to achieve this - Cascading in Koa.
as explained by @Sebastian Hildebrandt, Koa does this by yielding downstream and then flowing the control back upstream

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'll try to explain it using a very simple example:

```js
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

// middleware
app.use(async function (ctx, next) {
    console.log(1)
    await next();
    console.log(3)
});

// response
app.use(ctx => {
    console.log(2)
});

app.listen(3000);
```

If you call `localhost:3000` in your browser, the following will happen in your app:

- The first `app.use` that you fired here was the `middleware`. So the request flow goes into that one first, logs `1`to the console.
- Then, when you see this `await next()`, it downstreams to the next `use`.
- Here we just log `2` to the console. When this is finished (and no further await next is seen in the second `use`) the flow goes back to the first one which actually waited till the second one was finished.
- Here we then continue with logging `3` to the console.

Hope this makes it a little more clear.

Comment: Just to clarify, if you **didn't** use `await`, `console.log(3)` would be executed _synchronously_, so it would be unpredictable... So it might run before `console.log(2)`, or it might run after... It just depends how long `console.log(2)` takes to run.

Answer (score 3):

No, It is not necessary. It is depend on your requirement. 
you use next() function when you call next middleware.

**Check your router module and its version. I have use koa-router module and its version is 7.2.0 for routing. It self handle await next.**

```
'use strict';

const Koa = require('koa'),
    router = require('koa-router'),
    app = new Koa();

let pubRouter = new router();
let securedRouter = new router();

let mapper = require('./mapper'),

// assign router to corresponding function
mapper(pubRouter, securedRouter);

app .use(logger(config.app.log))    
.use(bodyParser())
.use(pubRouter.routes()).use(pubRouter.allowedMethods())
    .use(jwt({
        secret: publicKey,
        algorithms: ['RS256']
    }))
    .use(async(ctx, next) => {
        console.log('\n\n\n\n\n', ctx.state.user);
        await next();
    })
    .use(securedRouter.routes()).use(securedRouter.allowedMethods())
    .use(async(ctx, next) => {
        ctx.body = 'Invalid URL!!!';
    });

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server listening on port: ${port}`));
```