# How to get / and /:someText in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

```
 app.get('/',function(req,res,next){
       app.use(express.static(html file);
       next();
    });

app.get('/:someText',function(req,res){
var x = req.params.someText;
res.send(x);
});
```

I am getting the output for both, but nothing getting the CSS for that `express.static(html)` file.

Answer (score 2):

As i can see from code you missing send in get / .

```
app.get('/',function(req,res,next){
   //something
   //in here add res.send() and all OK.
});
```

Check this to understand what next is for.

[What is the parameter "next" used for in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695629/what-is-the-parameter-next-used-for-in-express)

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using `express.static` isn't right. You shouldn't pass it a single file to return, that's `sendFile`. `express.static` is used to serve up a entire directory and should be called outside the `get` handler.

For example, this would serve up a directory called `public` at the root of your URL. Any requests for files that aren't found would be passed on through the middleware/router chain to the next handler:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Importantly this should appear before your calls to `app.get`, `app.post`, etc. and not inside a handler.

So if you've got a file at `public/myfile.html` that would be served up at `http://localhost:3000/myfile.html`, where I've assumed your server is at `localhost:3000`. If you wanted to add an extra section of path to the URL, e.g. `http://localhost:3000/stat/myfile.html` that would be:

```
app.use('/stat', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

If you wanted to serve up a single file then you could use `sendFile`, a bit like this:

```
app.get('/myfile.html', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/myfile.html'));
});
```

Note that this is singling out a particular file so any resources such as CSS would need to be handled separately. If the HTML, CSS, etc. are all in the same folder it would make sense to use `express.static` to serve up the entire directory instead.

It is also worth noting that `express.static` has a setting called `index` that defaults to serving up a file called `index.html` if a request comes in for '/'.

Further reading:

- https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
- https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static
- https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile