# What parameters does next() take in Express

Tags: javascript, express, middleware

I am currently building an API thanks to Express.js, and I still can not believe how amazing it is. I figured out how to use middlewares, handling requests and responses, how to go to the next middleware ... But there is something that triggers me a lot, which is `next()`.

I know what `next()` is, I just can't figure out what kind of parameters can `next()` take, and what they will do. At first I thought it was to pass data to the next middleware, turned out I was wrong, there is `req.locals` for this.

Can someone enlighten me on this ?

Comment: have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695629/what-is-the-parameter-next-used-for-in-express ?

Comment: I have, but putting an error in it does not really help me, I would like to know what kind pf parameter(s) can we put in it an what for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three  choices for calling `next()`:

**1. Continue routing.**  If you just want to continue routing to the next route handler in the chain that matches this route, then you just call it with no parameters:

```
next();
```

This is most often used in middleware:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // set an item in the session and then continue routing
    req.session.xxx = "foo";
    next();
});
```

**2. Abort routing with an error to your centralized error handler.**  If you want to set an error and have routing skip to your generalized error handler, then you can pass an error:

```
next(new Error("timeout contacting database"));
```

This will then invoke your general error handling route and pass it that specific error where your general error handling code can decide what to do.  This allows you to centralize your error handling response code in one place.  Examples of using `next(err)` are [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.route).

You can see [the doc for generalized error handling in Express](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) for examples on how that works.

**3. Skip route handlers in this router, continue routing in other routers.** If you want to skip all route handlers in the current router, but continue with any other routes that might be registered, then you can do this:

```
next('route');
```

From the doc:

> You can provide multiple callback functions that behave just like middleware, except that these callbacks can invoke `next('route')` to bypass the remaining route callback(s). You can use this mechanism to impose pre-conditions on a route, then pass control to subsequent routes if there is no reason to proceed with the current route.

If you repeatedly search for "next(" on [this page of the doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.all), you will find lots of examples.  There's an example of this usage [here in the doc](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router).

---

FYI, Express 5 may add some new uses for `next()` because it may return a promise that lets you know when routing is now completely done.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed to know !