# How mongoose middleware works and what is next()?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
userSchema.pre('save',async function(next){
   //hash the password before saving user to database
   next()
})
```

Hey guys I'm trying to understand the concept of middleware in mongoose. Assuming that I have an userSchema that I run the pre hook on to hash the password before saving the user to the database. On the surface, as far as I understand, the above code that I have will hash the password (not the important part for this question) and then call next() to signal that the function is done. However, I am trying to understand how things work under the hood. I want to know what is next() ? Can you guys walk me through an example of how everything works together under the hood from start to end once the code get executed or somehow help me to have a better understanding of this concept? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the parameter "next" used for in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695629/what-is-the-parameter-next-used-for-in-express)

Comment: A mongoose middleware will trigger whenever you perform an operation with your database, In the above example, whenever you perform a save operation to your users collection the callback function will execute before the save operation is performed (since it is a pre middleware). The next simply means to not block the execution and carry forward to the next mongoose middleware (if it exists) or to your actual save operation. Your middleware should always call the next() else you code is blocked.

Comment: So I assume that the mongoose API is implemented so that it will call next() in this case right? And the next function is given to me by mongoose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short : with the `pre` method you can register listeners for certain events of your Schemas. So `pre('save', callback)` will fire whenever you save a document of said Model. `pre` means it will execute before the event, so it can be used (for example) to hash a password before saving it to the document.

However, you have several options to define them, see below :

The combination of using an `async` callback function and providing the `next` parameter is not necessary, you can either :

#### use normal callback with next parameter

the `next` parameter is a function provided to you by mongoose to have a way out, or to tell mongoose you are done and to continue with the next step in the execution chain. Also it is possible to pass an `Error` to `next` it will stop the execution chain.

```js
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  // do stuff
  
  if (error) { return next(new Error("something went wrong"); }
  return next(null);
});
```

### use async callback

Here the execution chain will continue once your async callback has finished. If there is an error and you want to break/stop execution chain you just `throw` it

```js
schema.pre('save', async function() {
  // do stuff
  await doStuff()
  await doMoreStuff()

  if (error) { throw new Error("something went wrong"); }
  return;
});
```

Straight from the docs : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre

## Example

```js
const { Schema, model }  = require('mongoose');

const SomeSchema = new Schema ({
  name : { type : String }
});

SomeSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  console.log('pre save fired!');
  return next();
});

const Some = model('Some', SomeSchema);

console.log('before create');
const doc = new Some({ name : 'test' });
doc.save((err) => {
  console.log('after saved');
});
```

This will output

```sh
before create
pre save fired!
after saved
```

Comment: Hey Pascal this is helpful. I just have one more question. Why with async function the next callback is not necessary anymore? Does this have to do with the nature of async function, which is to always return a promise so that when async function returns, the next step can handle the promise?

Comment: Mongoose is aware of what you specify as callback. So if the callback returns a  promise (async function) mongoose will wait for the promise to be resolved or rejected. If it's a normal function the use to call next is required otherwise the chain will hang

Comment: Glad i could help !

Comment: Let me know if there is still anything unclear, otherwise please accept as correct answer ! Thanks !