# How next() works here?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i just do password encryption before saving it in db, i just want to know how next() works here?
i know that next() helps us to jump one middleware to next middleware.

**userModel.js**

```
....
....
//below will encrypt password before saving user in db
//password is the field of  documents og mongodb

userSchema.pre("save", async function () {
  console.log(this.password);

  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    next();
  }

  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
});
....
....
```

//full code userModel.js

```
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
const bcrypt=require("bcryptjs");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique:true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  pic: {
    type: String,
    default:
      "https://icon-library.com/images/anonymous-avatar-icon/anonymous-avatar-icon-25.jpg",
  },
},
{
    timestamps:true,
});


//below compare given password with before password
userSchema.methods.matchPassword=async function(enteredPassword){
console.log("this.password",this.password)
return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword,this.password)
}


//below will encrypt password before saving user in db
userSchema.pre("save", async function () {
  console.log(this.password);

  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    next();
  }

  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
});

//mongoose.model(<Collectionname>, <CollectionSchema>)
//generally const "User" and  "User" in mongoose.model() written in same name
const User=new mongoose.model("User",userSchema);

module.exports=User;
```

I am new in node js please help me to understand middleware

Comment: Can you show the larger context where this function is located?  Like show the whole middleware function it's in?

Comment: The `next` must come from a function surrounding your code, like `app.use(..., function(req, res, next) {...})`.

Comment: @jfriend00 in userModel, means whre i define structure of documents

Comment: i have attached full userModel code

Comment: The code you show does now show where `next` comes from (and that's what your question is about) so there is still apparently relevant code missing here.  We have no idea what this `next` function is or where it comes from.  One would assume (based purely on its name) that it's something like the `next()` used in Express routing, but honestly we don't really know what it is or where it comes from based on the code you show.  It could be something different.

Comment: It's mongoose pre-save hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see more about middleware in mongoose here:

[How mongoose middleware works and what is next()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65463458/how-mongoose-middleware-works-and-what-is-next)

In short, `next()` will **tell mongoose you are done and to continue with the next step in the execution chain**. In your example, it will execute the "save" command to save the password to database if the password is not modified and go to next callback (if has).