# Axios Post request to Express backend gives 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, ejs

I have a simple blog site using EJS, Express, and Axios. No frontend framework - plain JS and EJS. I'm still relatively new to Express and Axios.
Trying to do a simple `POST` request with Axios to the router file `router.post("/admin/posts/create-post", adminCreatePost)` and get a `POST http://localhost:3000/admin/posts/create-post 404 (Not Found)` error in the browser console.

The `adminCreatePost` function is from a separate controller file. I commented out all code and put a simple `console.log("hello from the controller")` in the controller and it does log the message, but still get the `404` error in the browser console. So the `adminCreatePost` required in doesn't seem to be the issue.

I've triple checked the `url` I pass in to Axios `POST` call. I tried a simple `GET` request with Axios to make sure Axios itself wasn't the problem - the `GET` request worked.

I'm sure it's probably something simple/silly I'm not thinking about or overlooking. Any thoughts?

If you need more info, happy to answer.

#### savePost.js on the frontend

```
    document.getElementById('save-post-button').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        let postContent = [];
        let textAreas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
        const arrayOfTextAreas = Array.prototype.slice.call(textAreas);
        arrayOfTextAreas.forEach(element => {
            const block = new Object();
            block.type = element.dataset.blockType;
            block.contents = element.value;
            console.log(block);
            postContent.push(block);
        })

        let newPost = {
            postReadyToView: Boolean(document.getElementById('new--ready-for-viewers').value),
            postPath: document.getElementById('new--post-path').value,
            postTitle: document.getElementById('new--post-title').value,
            postDate: document.getElementById('new--email-subscribers-date').value,
            postUpdateDate: null,
            postContent: postContent
        };

        axios.post("/admin/posts/create-post", newPost)
            .then(res => console.log(res))
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    })
```

#### router.js on backend

```
const {postREQ_adminCreatePost } = require("./controllers/controllerAdmin");

router.post("/admin/posts/create-post", postREQ_adminCreatePost)

module.exports = router;
```

#### controllerAdmin.js on backend

```
exports.postREQ_adminCreatePost = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('hello from controller');
  next();
}
```

Comment: Remove `next()` try `res.send("")` before the end of the `postREQ_adminCreatePost` function

Comment: @Woohaik thank you! that worked. when do you use `next` vs `res.send`?

Comment: [What is the parameter "next" used for in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695629/what-is-the-parameter-next-used-for-in-express)

Comment: @Phil thank you for that